# Mismatch in results of iperf and iptraf

Tags: linux, networking, iperf

I ran TCP throughput from client(iperf -c IP -i1 -p19223) to server(iperf -s -i1 -p19223).

The stats showed me bandwidth of ~5Gbps. However, when I ran iptraf on the server, it reported that the server was receiving only around 600Mbps.

Is this a known issue?

```
Server/Client: RHEL 6
Iperf: iperf-2.0.5-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Are you sure _iptraf_ isn't showing wrong statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once again encountered similar issue of mismatch in the results of, this time, [iperf3](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/iperf3-3.1.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and [iptraf-ng](https://archlinux.pkgs.org/rolling/archlinux-extra-x86_64/iptraf-ng-1.1.4-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.html)(This time I was using RHEL 7.5).

There were huge differences in the reported results by both applications. I found out that in this case(and I believe this was true in the earlier case as well), the culprit was iptraf!

The solution here is to **stop using iptraf/iptraf-ng**.

**Use [iftop](https://www.unixmen.com/iftop-a-network-bandwidth-monitoring-tool-for-linux/) instead**.

There might be [some difference in the results](https://blog.famzah.net/2015/06/25/iperf-and-iftop-accuracy/) shown on iftop and iperf as well but that will be minor(due to some unit mismatch).